# Basic measure theory question

Tags: measure-theory

It is a very important question for me.

If we define the measure ${\mu}$ like this:  ${\mu}=\left\lbrace
  \begin{array}{l}
    {\mu} (\lbrace a \rbrace )>0 \\
    {\mu} (\mathbb{R}-{\lbrace a\rbrace })=0 \\
    \end{array}
  \right. $

How can I justify the following equalities? I don´t completely understand them.
  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{ipx}d{\mu}(x)=\int_{\lbrace a \rbrace} \! e^{ipx}d{\mu}(x)+\int_{\mathbb{R}-\lbrace a \rbrace } \! e^{ipx}d{\mu}(x)=\int_{\lbrace a \rbrace} \! e^{ipx}d{\mu}(x)=e^{ipc}{\mu} ({a})$$

Comment: You are defining $\mu$ in terms of $\mu$... badly. You probably want to edit it to make what you want precise.

Comment: Thanks, James. But the definition is okay, I mean that $\mu$ is suported on the point $a$.

Comment: Sure, it's called the Dirac measure, for $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$. But, what you have written, using standard conventions for reading mathematics is nonsense. You want something like $\mu(X) = \begin{cases} k & \text{if } a\in X \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mean exactly that.

Comment: As for the math, the first equality follows from additivity of the integral over disjoint measurable subsets. The second equality follows from the fact that the integral of any function over a set of measure 0 is 0, and the final one is direct from the definition, as the intergrand is constant on the domain $\{a\}$ which has measure $\mu(a)$.

Comment: Thank you very much James. I understand all, but the last equality. May be I don´t understand the definition... Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24571/discussion-between-james-and-edin-91).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you notice that

$$\left(\Bbb{R}\setminus\{a\}\right)\cap\{a\}=\varnothing$$

then

$$\mu\left(\Bbb{R}\right)=\mu\left(\left(\Bbb{R}\setminus\{a\}\right)\cup\{a\}\right)=\mu\left(\Bbb{R}\setminus\{a\}\right)+\mu(\{a\})$$

because of the defining $\sigma$-additivity of the measures. The first equality is justified. Moreover

$$\mu\left(\Bbb{R}\setminus\{a\}\right)=0$$

so integrals on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{a\}$ are null and, through the first equality

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ipx}\,d\mu=\int_{\{a\}}e^{ipx}\,d\mu$$

As

$$e^{ipx}\big|_{x=a}=e^{ipa}$$

is constant, you have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{ipx}\,d\mu=e^{ipa}\ \int_{\{a\}}d\mu=e^{ipa}\ \mu(\{a\})$$

I don't think the requirement $\mu(\{a\})>0$ is needed in any way, other than to characterize the measure.